# I18n Twitter application name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, internationalization

I have an app that has different names for different languages. How do I reflect that on my twitter app register?  I want to show a specific name from a specific domain, when the user try to auth.

At app side I'm using Rails with ominiauth and twitter gems. I need some ideas guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't programmatically change app name (or callback url) for safety reasons. The best thing you can do is create multiple apps with different names. When user signs in with twitter (using his app in his language) , you save his token/secret along with which app he used.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique app on Twitter Developers with a unique name ("toto Twitter" for example) and explain to your users that the application is referred as "toto Twitter" in the list of the applications they authorized.

izeed's solution is nice but it implies that the user has to authenticate again each time it chooses a new language. It is not ergonomic and it might flood the user's list of authorized application.
Imagine an user that has already used 15 different idioms. It had to authenticate 15 times the app and it would have 15 "toto Twitter_lang" in its list of authorized applications just for your app. That's not very convenient.